# regular expression for a tree hierarchy string extraction

Tags: regex

suppose I have tree hierarchy string like this `"/grand_parent/parent/child"` (three level) or `"/parent/child"` (two level), `"/child"` (one level) and I tried `"^(/[^/]*)"` could extract the first level `"/grand_parent"`, and wondering if I want to extract the first two levels if there exists, 
e.g.

- extract `"/grand_parent/parent"` for `"/grand_parent/parent/child"`
- extract `"/parent/child"` for `"/parent/child"`
- extract nothing for `"/child"`

what is the suggested regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe you'd want to design an expression similar to:

```
^(?=\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)
```

not sure though:

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/vwBi5n/1/)

which would work the same without the capturing group:

```
^(?=\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PvWxg7/1/)

> Escapings are just for the demos.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `^/[^/]+/[^/]+`?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qIFma8/1/)